# How do clients connect to hyperledger fabric network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

If i have a fabric network with multiple peers, how can, say, a mobile app (representing the user) query data from that network ? 
It would need the IP address of at least 1 peer, but how do i deliver this to the app as dynamically as possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop a gateway application using one of the below SDK's

Fabric comes with

- NodeJS SDK
- Go SDK
- JAVA SDK

This gateway application will expose api's so that mobile app can consume whenever it required

I here by mention a sample open source fabcar application [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release/fabcar)

Comment: but how does that gateway app know which peers are on the network ?

Comment: from the network sample i see here, the peers are predefined https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/first-network/connection-org3.json

Comment: you will have to give at least one peer info so that gateway app will resolve other peers for you